# gitlab pre-receive hook to run python unit tests for a every push and merge

Tags: python, gitlab, githooks

I am using the gitlab server for code maintenance. Now I planned to run unit test for a every push from my developer team.

As I now, that using the CI tools we can achieve this. But now I am thinking of doing the same with git pre-receive hook.

I would like to define a pre-receive hook in the gitlab server and will place a python script which will run the unit tests. Once all my tests success then the system will exit with status 0 and it will allow the push otherwise denies the push from client side.

I would like to know, it is good practice to run unit tests in the pre-receive hook.? If not, any other alternative solutions other than CI tool ?

Comment: any one can help on this ?

Comment: https://github.com/innogames/igcommit could be a good starting point.